# Issue with compiling the .Net program

Tags: c#, .net

I want to run `.Net`project which works with a `REST API`. I have successfully retarget this solution to `.Net 7.0` using `.NET Upgrade Assistant` but I still get the following issues:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ConfigureWebHostDefaults' and no accessible extension method 'ConfigureWebHostDefaults' accepting a first argument of type 'IHostBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\Program.cs    36  Active
Error   CS0653  Cannot apply attribute class 'ApplicationPart' because it is abstract   BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\AssemblyInfo.cs   3   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IWebHostEnvironment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\Controllers\ErrorController.cs    19  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IWebHostEnvironment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\Startup.cs    59  Active
Error   CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddControllers' and no accessible extension method 'AddControllers' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\Startup.cs    34  Active
Error   CS1061  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseRouting' and no accessible extension method 'UseRouting' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\Startup.cs    68  Active
Error   CS1061  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseAuthorization' and no accessible extension method 'UseAuthorization' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\Startup.cs    69  Active
Error   CS1061  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseEndpoints' and no accessible extension method 'UseEndpoints' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\Startup.cs    70  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IEndpointRouteBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\Startup.cs    70  Active
Warning MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll].
        C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll".
            C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [].
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\BOne.Ewa.Api.Common.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\BOne.Ewa.Api.Common.dll".
            BOne.Ewa.Api.Common
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll".
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2364    
Warning MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.core\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll].
        C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.core\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.core\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll".
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [].
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll".
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll".
            Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen   BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2364    
Warning MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    "Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.objectpool\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll].
        C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.objectpool\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.objectpool\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll".
            C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.objectpool\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll
    References which depend on "Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [].
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll".
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2364    
Warning MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch, Version=3.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch, Version=3.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.jsonpatch\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.dll].
        C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.jsonpatch\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.jsonpatch\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.dll".
            C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.jsonpatch\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.dll
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch, Version=3.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [].
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll".
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2364    
Warning MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll].
        C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll".
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [].
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll".
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll".
            Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen   BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2364    
Warning MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll].
        C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll".
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [].
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll".
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll".
            Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger
            Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll".
            Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI    BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2364    
Warning MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.html.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions.dll].
        C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.html.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.html.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions.dll".
            C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.html.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions.dll
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [].
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll".
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2364    
Warning MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll].
        C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll".
            C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [].
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll".
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2364    
Warning MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    "Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.http.headers\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll].
        C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.http.headers\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.http.headers\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll".
            C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.http.headers\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll
    References which depend on "Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [].
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll".
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2364    
Warning MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.routing\2.2.2\lib\netcoreapp2.2\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll].
        C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.routing\2.2.2\lib\netcoreapp2.2\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.routing\2.2.2\lib\netcoreapp2.2\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll".
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [].
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll".
            Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger
            Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen   BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2364    
Warning MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll].
        C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll".
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [].
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll".
            Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen
        C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\BOne.Ewa.Api\lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll".
            Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI    BOne.Ewa.Api    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2364    
Warning MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apiexplorer\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.dll].
        C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apiexplorer\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apiexplorer\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.dll".
            C:\Users\cobra\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apiexplorer\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.dll
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Any ideas what dependencies still could be missing? Thanks.

Comment: You need to target .net core, not framework

Comment: @DanielA.White

Ok. I see there only .Net Frameworks. Any documentation link how to retarget this solution to be able to select the .Net Core? Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I have successfully retarget this solution but I still get some issues. I will change the main post to describe those issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Great!

I fixed those issues by installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` using `NuGet Package Manager` in `Visual Studio 2022`. Now, it compiles the `.Net` project successfully. This issue is resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You should add:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
```

…at the beginning of your `Startup.cs` file.

Comment: I have added but it still displays those errors. I think, some dependencies are missing there.